# How do I submit a batch set of images for OCR analysis to Azure Computer Vision API in a single transaction?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I'm looking to see if Azure Computer Vision API supports submitting a collection of images/documents for batch processing for OCR analysis for dense text document (text heavy). 
Specifically, I'm looking to see if this is offered as a transactional operation. 
Is my only option to use the single image per request?

Is my only option to engineer code that does the batching myself?
Any insight is appreciated. 
Ive looked at the documentation here and dont see batch processing mentioned.

v2.0

https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/2afb498089f74080d7ef85eb

v3.0

https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/computer-vision-v3-ga/operations/5d986960601faab4bf452005

If I have (as an input) a set of images (pdf,tiff,etc) and would like to get OCR for each in a transactional way (all or nothing), what existing endpoints are available?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the Read operation of Azure Cognitive Services takes only 1 document (whether direct send or by URL) at a time.

It can process several pages at a time for PDF and TIFF (up to 2000 pages are processed).

Processing multiple pages at once does not improve the cost, as each processed page is count as a "feature" which is the cost unit

Comment: Do you happen to know if the number of pages processed per second changes depending on whether you submit a single request vs a request per page?

Comment: I guess there is a queueing system here as it is an asynchronous operation so yes, there might be an impact. But again, that's my own opinion/guess on that and I'm not working at Microsoft to confirm that